# Sample exercises key words array length and indexes

Tags: arrays, indexing

Trying to improve my JAVA  and was hoping for some help with the below exercises as i am struggling a bit. I have got as far as declaring the integers and doing the sums. I cant seem to work out how to do every thing else. Please help

1. Given an array of integers, find the sum of first half and the sum of second half. If the array length is not even numbered, return -1.
   e.g
   In array below,  LHS sum = 10, RHS sum= 26.
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8

AND

2. Given an array of integers, find ‘element to be found’ and return the index .If not found return -1.
   e.g
   In array below, if ‘element to be found’ = 4, then return index= 3.
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7

My (poor) attempt at 1

```
int a=1;
int b=2;
int c=3;
int d=4;
int e=5;
int f=6;
int g=7;
int h=8;
int LHSSum=a+b+c+d;
int RHSSum=e+f+g+h;
int arrayLength=;

if  (arrayLength !=)
    then
    System.out.println("-1");
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first question:

```
int lhs = 0; //Lower half sum
int uhs = 0; //Upper half sum

int myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

if  (arrayLength !=) {
    System.out.println("-1");
}
else {

    for (i = 0; i < (myArray.length/2); i++)
    {
        lhs = lhs + myArray[i];
        System.out.println(lhs);
    }


    for (i = (myArray.length/2); i < myArray.length; i++)
    {
        uhs = uhs + myArray[i];
        System.out.println(uhs);
    }

}
```

(I did it in the case of your array length was even)

Comment: Thank you i will give your code a go. Worked on 1 a bit mor this is what i can up with

Comment: List<Integer> array = Arrays.asList(1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7);
int a = Arrays.asList(array).indexOf(3);
if (array.contains(4)) 
System.out.println(a);
else
 System.out.println("-1");

Comment: Hi Olivier tried to run your code in codechef.com. I am getting errors. I am probably doing something wrong I will play with your code more